# ASP.NET delivering download of locked files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, file-upload, download

I have been trying some approaches, and get this one.

What I really need is something like Response.TransmitFile (or MVC File method, that uses TransmitFile  behind it). But using FileShare.ReadWrite instead of Read.

I am testing with a 2GB file. TransmitFile doesn't have memory or CPU footprint.

I tried to do something similar, but I don't know if I am at right path. This method doesn't consume memory, but consumes 7% of cpu at peak

```
    private void Download(string caminho)
    {
        const int tamanhoBuffer = 8192;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + Path.GetFileName(caminho) + "");


        using (var fs = new FileStream(caminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString());

            byte[] conteudo = new byte[tamanhoBuffer];
            int size;

            while (Response.IsClientConnected && (size = fs.Read(conteudo, 0, conteudo.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Response.OutputStream.Write(conteudo, 0, size);
                Response.Flush();
            }

            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want a file that is being downloaded to be available for writing? What do you expect to happen to the download?

Comment: The problem is, I need to send a file that is already open by users

Comment: If it is opened by any user, and that user is making changes, you should not make it available for downloading.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But we are using a DWF viewer and it is getting Write lock, even though it is read-only application

Comment: To be safe, you should use a copy of the file for downloading.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing it, but how to delete these temp files?

Comment: I get the feeling you need more of a "repository", taking care of all the issues involved, like SVN, instead of a download site?